# Log4j2 Deleting Old Logs Not Working

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I am attempting to programmatically configure Log4j2 v2.11.1 to delete old files using the new Delete action as part of the DefaultRolloverStrategy.

As you can see from my code below, I have the system set up to create log files each day and to roll over the file when its size reaches 1 MB.

I've attempted to add the Delete action onto the DefaultRolloverStrategy with two conditions - IfFileName and IfLastModified.  The IfFileName specifies that the name of the file must be app.*.log and the IfLastModified component specifies that the file must also be a day old in order to be deleted.

For whatever reason, this is not working.  The log files are properly created each day and rolled over based on the size, but the files older than a day are not deleted.  There are no errors in the app server log to indicate that I made a mistake in the configuration.

```
static Configuration createConfiguration(String name, ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder) {
    builder.setConfigurationName(name);
    LayoutComponentBuilder layoutBuilder  = builder.newLayout("PatternLayout").addAttribute("pattern", "%d [%t] %-5level: %msg%n");
    ComponentBuilder triggeringPolicy = builder.newComponent("Policies");
    triggeringPolicy.addComponent(builder.newComponent("TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy").addAttribute("interval", "1").addAttribute("modulate", "true"));
    triggeringPolicy.addComponent(builder.newComponent("SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy").addAttribute("size", "1 MB"));

    ComponentBuilder rolloverStrategy = builder.newComponent("DefaultRolloverStrategy");

    ComponentBuilder ifFileName = builder.newComponent("IfFileName").addAttribute("glob", "app.*.log");
    ComponentBuilder ifLastModified = builder.newComponent("IfLastModified").addAttribute("age", "1d");

    ComponentBuilder deleteAction = builder.newComponent("Delete").addAttribute("basePath", "C:\\applogs\\").addAttribute("maxDepth", "1");
    deleteAction.addComponent(ifFileName).addComponent(ifLastModified);

    rolloverStrategy.addComponent(deleteAction);

    AppenderComponentBuilder appenderBuilder = builder.newAppender("rolling", "RollingFile")
            .addAttribute("fileName", "C:\\applogs\\app.log")
            .addAttribute("filePattern", "C:\\applogs\\app_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log")
            .add(layoutBuilder)
            .addComponent(triggeringPolicy)
            .addComponent(rolloverStrategy);
    builder.add(appenderBuilder);
    builder.add(builder.newRootLogger(Level.INFO).add(builder.newAppenderRef("rolling")).addAttribute("additivity", false));
    Configuration config = builder.build();
    Configurator.initialize(config);
    return config;
}
```

On a side note, if I remove the code for the delete action and add the following line, the system properly removes the oldest log file that was rolled over and keeps the latest three.

```
ComponentBuilder rolloverStrategy = builder.newComponent("DefaultRolloverStrategy").addAttribute("max", "3");
```

Any ideas why my age deletion setup is not working?  I've tried removing the IfLastModified component to see if all files are deleted, and that also does not work.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions that you could provide.

Comment: Try setting system property `log4j2.debug` to `TRACE` to get detailed internal log4j logs during configuration and rollover. https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#troubleshooting  Also, have you tried asking on the log4j user mailing list?

Comment: @RemkoPopma Thank you for the suggestions.  I didn't make any changes to the code I listed above or make any other environment changes, but what I noticed is that the deletion action didn't execute until a rollover event fired due to the time or size policy being  triggered.  This was a misunderstanding on my part.  Thanks again for your assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the event that someone else stumbles across my question, I wanted to provide an answer.  I did not make any changes to the original code that I listed in my question.  However, the delete action was finally fired when a rollover event occurred due to the time or size policy being triggered.  This caused the log files older than one day - based on the last modified date - to be removed.

One other note.  Someone responded that I should turn on log4j2 debugging in order to see internal details about how the logging system is processing the configuration and rollover of files.  The application server that my application is running on is JBoss, and I noticed that adding the log4j2.debug JVM argument with the value TRACE did not enable this internal logging.

Instead, I did not set the value of the log4j2.debug argument as shown below.

```
-Dlog4j2.debug
```

This did the trick when added to the JAVA_OPTS variable in the standalone.bat script file in JBoss.